# has_many / belongs_to : display each associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models and its associated tables link together in a belongs_to and has_many relationship.

Here is the schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130827203308) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text    "message"
    t.integer "student_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["student_id"], name: "index_posts_on_student_id", using: :btree

  create_table "students", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "number"
    t.string   "college"
    t.string   "password"
    t.float    "budget"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

I can go to rails console and do

```
a = Student.find(1)
c = a.posts.create(:message => "testing")
c.save!

(0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

I don't know how to draw it back out in the view. I don't know how to draw it back out in rails console as well.

I have in my index.html.erb view with

```
Message: <%= @student.posts.message %>
```

and with `@student = Student.find(1)` in my controller

and getting

```
undefined method `message'
```

in my localhost:3000

Its not a method. I am trying to draw something from my table.

Comment: It says method because you call `message` on a `Student` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@student.posts` return a list of Post objects belonging to this particular Student object.

You need to loop through each posts of the student to display its message:

```
student = Student.first # retrieves the first Student of the DB
posts = student.posts # retrieves the student's posts
posts.each do |post| # loop through each post of the student
  puts post.message # outputs the content of the message attribute of the post
end
```

In the view, it would be kind of the same:

```
Student: 
<%= @student.first_name + ' ' + @student.last_name %>

Posts: 
<% @student.posts.each do |post| %>
  Post #<%= post.id %>
  Message: <%= post.message %>
<% end %>
```